# Scrape nested span tag on loop with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a nested html tags and I'm trying to scrape the text and link out of it. But for weird reason it's not working.

I marked the line I want to scrape with  this emoji. One is the Link and Another one is text.

```html
<div class="q-box" role="list" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
    <div>
      <a class="q-box qu-display--block qu-cursor--pointer qu-hover--textDecoration--none Link___StyledBox-t2xg9c-0 KlcoI" target="_blank" href="https://www.quora.com/Can-Facebook-see-who-viewed-your-profile" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: inherit;">
          <div class="q-box qu-hover--textDecoration--underline qu-tapHighlight--none qu-display--flex qu-alignItems--center" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;">
             <div class="q-flex qu-alignItems--center qu-py--tiny qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                <div class="q-box qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                   <div class="q-text qu-color--gray_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                      <div class="q-box qu-py--tiny" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                         <span class="q-text qu-color--blue_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                            <div class="q-flex qu-flexDirection--row" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                               <div class="q-inline qu-flexWrap--wrap" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline; max-width: 100%;">
                                  <div class="q-text qu-truncateLines--2 puppeteer_test_question_title" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <span class="q-box qu-userSelect--text" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <span style="background: none;">Can Facebook see who viewed your profile?</span></span></div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <a class="q-box qu-display--block qu-cursor--pointer qu-hover--textDecoration--none Link___StyledBox-t2xg9c-0 KlcoI" target="_blank" href="https://onlinesocialmediasolution.quora.com/How-to-view-a-private-Facebook-profile" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: inherit;">
          <div class="q-box qu-hover--textDecoration--underline qu-tapHighlight--none qu-display--flex qu-alignItems--center" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;">
             <div class="q-flex qu-alignItems--center qu-py--tiny qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                <div class="q-box qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                   <div class="q-text qu-color--gray_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                      <div class="q-box qu-py--tiny" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                         <span class="q-text qu-color--blue_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                            <div class="q-flex qu-flexDirection--row" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                               <div class="q-inline qu-flexWrap--wrap" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline; max-width: 100%;">
                                  <div class="q-text qu-truncateLines--2 puppeteer_test_question_title" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <span class="q-box qu-userSelect--text" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                  <span style="background: none;">How do you view a private Facebook profile?</span></span></div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <a class="q-box qu-display--block qu-cursor--pointer qu-hover--textDecoration--none Link___StyledBox-t2xg9c-0 KlcoI" target="_blank" href="https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-tell-if-non-friends-have-viewed-your-Facebook-profile" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: inherit;">
          <div class="q-box qu-hover--textDecoration--underline qu-tapHighlight--none qu-display--flex qu-alignItems--center" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;">
             <div class="q-flex qu-alignItems--center qu-py--tiny qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                <div class="q-box qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                   <div class="q-text qu-color--gray_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                      <div class="q-box qu-py--tiny" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                         <span class="q-text qu-color--blue_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                            <div class="q-flex qu-flexDirection--row" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                               <div class="q-inline qu-flexWrap--wrap" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline; max-width: 100%;">
                                  <div class="q-text qu-truncateLines--2 puppeteer_test_question_title" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <span class="q-box qu-userSelect--text" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                        <span style="background: none;">How can you tell if non-friends have viewed your Facebook profile?</span></span></div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <a class="q-box qu-display--block qu-cursor--pointer qu-hover--textDecoration--none Link___StyledBox-t2xg9c-0 KlcoI" target="_blank" href="https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-see-your-own-Facebook-profile-from-the-view-of-a-non-friend" style="box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: inherit;">
          <div class="q-box qu-hover--textDecoration--underline qu-tapHighlight--none qu-display--flex qu-alignItems--center" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: relative;">
             <div class="q-flex qu-alignItems--center qu-py--tiny qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                <div class="q-box qu-flex--auto qu-overflow--hidden" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                   <div class="q-text qu-color--gray_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                      <div class="q-box qu-py--tiny" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                         <span class="q-text qu-color--blue_dark" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                            <div class="q-flex qu-flexDirection--row" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
                               <div class="q-inline qu-flexWrap--wrap" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline; max-width: 100%;">
                                  <div class="q-text qu-truncateLines--2 puppeteer_test_question_title" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <span class="q-box qu-userSelect--text" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                   <span style="background: none;">Is there a way to see your own Facebook profile from the view of a non-friend?</span></span></div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </span>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This is the Index.js file code I have done so far. But it's looping through all the marked emoji lines. Nor it's working.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  try {
    // loop through the selector and get the data
    await page.waitForSelector(
      '#root > div.q-box > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div'
    );
    const related = page.$eval(
      '#root > div.q-box > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.q-box.qu-mb--large > div > div:nth-child(2)',
      (el) => el.innerText
    );
    res.send(related);
  } catch (err) {
    // res.send(err, 500);
    console.log(err);
  }
  await browser.close();
```

Comment: Can you share the actual page? These browser-generated hyper-specific selectors seem prone to error. I suspect there's a better way, and/or extra JS behavior that makes this code fail.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen. I'm trying to scrape the Related Questions from right side of the page. https://www.quora.com/Can-you-really-see-who-viewed-your-profile-on-Facebook Everytime I'm facing different issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the Quora URL you provided in the comment, I retrieved the container box's CSS class which is `.q-sticky`. it helps to find the inner elements (links and link texts) more easily.

using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#child_combinator) and [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) you can compose patterns that can grab your desired elements:

- all links within the box: `'.q-sticky * > a'`
- all link texts within the box: `'.q-sticky * > .q-box.qu-userSelect--text'`

note: your initial code had an async issue: `const related = page.$eval(...` where you should `await` the `page.$eval` to avoid errors (the puppeteer methods mostly return Promises, that can be handled with awaiting them).

instead of `page.$eval` you could use its [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) variant (which is the "querySelectorAll" version) that can return an array of elements with the same selector.

finally, you can combine the two arrays as you need them (I used an `Array.map` oneliner below)

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.q-sticky * > a');
const relatedLinks = await page.$$eval('.q-sticky * > a', elems => elems.map((el) => el.href));
const relatedTitles = await page.$$eval('.q-sticky * > .q-box.qu-userSelect--text', elems => elems.map((el) => el.innerText));
    
const related = relatedLinks.map((linkel, i) => { return { link: linkel, title: relatedTitles[i] }});
console.log(related);
```